# RSYNC changes file termination and fails

Tags: rsync

have a strange, rarely occuring error on our Jenkins machines that execute rsync from python to perform some archiving tasks.

The error is:

```
rsync: rename "/OLD_PATH/internal/.my_config.json.MfXl7i" -> "internal/my_config.json": Permission denied (13)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]
```

The command with its error is:

```
rsync -az --no-p --no-g --chmod=ugo=rwX NEW_PATH/ OLD_PATH
returned non-zero exit status 23
```

The file which is written by the rest of the python script right before the rsync call is "my_config.json".
Where does the dot before that filename and that ending "MfXl7i" come from? Why does rsync change a file termination apparently?

Huge thanks in advance.

Comment: Under what account does this `rsync` command run? Please add the output of `ls -ld OLD_PATH/internal OLD_PATH/internal/my_config.json OLD_PATH/internal/.my*` to your question so we can see the permissions/ownerships.

Comment: What are the file systems in source and target folders, e.g. ext4, xfs, ...?

Comment: Extensions like .MfXl7i is often a result of text editors which have the file opened right now.

Comment: @WhiteOwl No, in this case it is a temporary file name by `rsync`. This can be avoided with the `--inplace` parameter. Likely irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant error message is in the first line:

```
rsync: rename "internal/.my_config.json.MfXl7i" -> "internal/my_config.json": Permission denied (13)
```

It means that the `rsync` command could synchronise the data but not write the new file.

Do you have write permissions on the file `internal/my_config.json`?  Perhaps the file exists and is write protected, or not owned by you?

You can find out by looking at that file and its containing folder:

```
# ls -ld internal internal/my_config.json
```

You need to be able to write the named file into the folder, e.g. by owning the folder, having read+write+execute permission for you on the folder and if the file exists it cannot have an immutable attribute or be read-only (you need write permissions on it).  Also, the folder needs to reside on a disk/partition which is not mounted read-only.